# C# exam application timer cheating issue

Tags: c#, timer

I have made an exam application in C# that has a timer, while taking exam suppose the candidate keeps on pressing the windows' minimize button (without releasing the mouse) at 1 minute and 30 seconds, the time pauses even if the candidate keeps on pressing the mouse for 10 minutes, but when the mouse is released the time resumes from the very second where it was paused i.e. 1 minute and 30 seconds. I want the timer to be continued without any pauses.

Comment: Clearly you are doing something in the UI thread that should not be done in the UI thread.  Please post your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What timer component are you using? `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`?

I suspect the `S.W.F.Timer` uses `SetTimer` API call which uses window messages which would explain what you are seeing, a threaded timer would be better.

You could also just use a thread, store a `DateTime.UtcNow` and every 100ms or something in the thread, get another `DateTime.UtcNow` and check the `TimeSpan` for the elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `System.Threading.Timer` class because that is supposed to work independently from windows messages

Answer (score 1):

You could record the `DateTime.UtcNow` when the test starts and monitor that `DateTime.UtcNow - startTime` in the [`Elapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) event of a timer. If the difference is greater than you want, you can end the test there.

Comment: You want to use UtcNow over Now because, although unlikely, the timezone/dst could change which would affect the value.